# На какой технологии написан этот сайт?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css-animation

Вот [ссылка](https://www.chelseacollective.com/brands) раздела сайта где разные бренды разбиты по одинаковым плиточкам. При разной ширины экрана, плитки также имеют разный размер. На больших расширениях к основным плиткам с контентом добавляются пустые.

Прошу помощи у тех кто знает, что это за js библиотека, плагин, или как это сделать самому.

Comment: С изменением сайта вопрос потеряет смысл. Проблема хорошо раскрыта в [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83).

Comment: Кстати, привет любителю Пратчетта. )

Answer (score 0):

Там все написано на чистом JS, причем весьма качественный код. Из внешних библиотек используется API Google Maps + Google Tag Manager. Еще нашел, что используют Pixi.js 3.0.6 (http://www.pixijs.com/, https://www.chelseacollective.com/assets/js/lib/pixi.min.js) и Hydra.js (https://www.chelseacollective.com/assets/js/hydra/hydra-thread.js). Они не используют какую-либо популярную CMS, скорее применяют внутренние разработки студии, которая делала этот сайт.

Comment: Поищите в этом чистом js вот это - `window.ASSETS` и гляньте, что в этом массиве лежит, и что дальше с этим массивом происходит

Comment: @Darth да, там используются некоторые библиотеки, беглым взглядом сразу не заметил.

Answer (score 0):

Там используются

- https://d3js.org/
- http://www.pixijs.com/

ох уж эти ограничения на длину ответа..

- http://www.varnish-cache.org/
- Гугл аналитика, гугл шрифты